# Firebase - Getting a unique ID across providers on iOS

Tags: ios, firebase

I have been searching around the Firebase documentation as well as SO and I came across [an SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687713/is-firebase-user-id-unique-per-provider-facebook-twitter-password) saying that Firebase now had a `uid` variable that was unique across all providers, but I do not see that available in the [Simple Login iOS SDK](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-ios-overview.html).

Is there a way to get/generate this unique ID across all providers in iOS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Engineer at Firebase] While the `uid` parameter is on the token generated and returned to the Firebase Simple Login iOS client, and available in the security rules via the `auth` variable, it looks like we're not currently exposing this on the `User` object returned to your methods.

**Update 2014/03/07**: Support for the `uid` has been added to the Firebase Simple Login iOS Client as of v1.3.0, available at https://cdn.firebase.com/ios/FirebaseSimpleLogin.framework-1.3.0.zip.

<strike>I'll work on adding that functionality for the next version of the Firebase Simple Login iOS client, but in the meantime you can use `<provider>:<user-id>` to simulate what the client is doing. I'll update this item once this feature has been added.</strike>

Comment: Thanks Rob! I was hoping the generation was something simple like that. I'll give it a try and let you know if I have any issues.